# Elastic search nested query - how to filter based only on first instance of nested document to answer filter

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have an object that contains an array of objects.
That array is mapped as nested. 
Let's say the array is a list of all the cars I've owned throughout the years.

I want to be able to search for all the people who at a specific timepoint had a 'Ford' specifically.

My data only has the 'purchase date' of the car.

So let's say I have a person that at one point had a ford, then switched to a Honda.

My nested filter would say:
"Give me all the people who their purchase date is less then or equal to 'specific timepoint' and their model is a 'Ford'"

Considering my data - I would get the person above answering truthfully on my query.

I would like to search for all the nested documents that are relevant to my timepoint and then only query the most recent sub document to see if the model is a Ford.

Is this possible in any way?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample mapping, document structure, the query what you are looking for along with the response

### Mapping:

```
PUT mycars
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "cars":{  
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{  
               "purchase_date":{  
                  "type":"date"
               },
               "type":{  
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{  
                     "keyword":{  
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "owner":{  
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{  
               "keyword":{  
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you notice the mapping, the nested field would be `cars` which has `purchase_date` as date field while `type` as text field with both text and keyword types available.

I've also added a field `owner` just for the sake of understanding and giving document an identity sort of.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST mycars/_doc/1
{
  "owner": "john",
  "cars":[
    {
      "type": "Ford",
      "purchase_date": "2017-01-01"
    },
    {
      "type": "Tesla",
      "purchase_date": "2019-01-01"
    }

    ]
}

POST mycars/_doc/2
{
  "owner": "jess",
  "cars":[
    {
      "type": "Ford",
      "purchase_date": "2017-01-01"
    }    
    ]
}

POST mycars/_doc/3
{
  "owner": "jenny",
  "cars":[
    {
      "type": "Ford",
      "purchase_date": "2019-01-01"
    }
    ]
}

POST mycars/_doc/4
{
  "owner": "tom",
  "cars":[
    {
      "type": "Ford",
      "purchase_date": "2016-01-01"
    }
    ]
}
```

Now your query is *Give me all the people who their purchase date is less then or equal to 'specific timepoint' and their model is a 'Ford'*

I have the first two and the last document falling for the query that you have with the date `2017-01-01`

So below query is what I have which **gives me all the people who have purchased `Ford` on or before `2018-01-01` AND no other car has been bought post `2018-01-01`**

### Query:

```
POST mycars/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cars",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "cars.type.keyword": "Ford"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "cars.purchase_date": {
                        "lte": "2018-01-01"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
      {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cars",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "cars.purchase_date": {
                        "gte": "2018-01-01"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've added `must_not` clause so as to filter the documents where the user would have ended up purchasing any other car after the date mentioned in the `must` clause.

Note that I have simply made use of [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query and the [Range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) query for the nested documents.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the time you took to answer my question. The problem is that John bought another car in the 01-07-2017 and it's a Tesla. In that case his most recent car as of 01-01-2018 is a Tesla and not a Ford. But the above query would return his document because he has a nested document that specifies all filters above.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a way too find all people who their most recent car purchase as of 'specific date' was a Ford. And not wether or not the bought a Ford sometime before that date. Is this possible? ( See comment above for example )

Comment: Please check now. I've added query at the end.

Comment: Oh I get your question now. Not sure if this is possible in direct querying but let me see what I can do.

Comment: @K.Daniel I do not think it is possible to do what you are looking for using Elasticsearch. You may have to add additional logic at the client level from the results my query would return. My query, would only *show documents where Ford has been bought before `2018-01-01` and no other car been bought post that date*. Please do review the query regardless and let me know if that could be useful.